# Java MD5 which one of these is correct?

Tags: java, algorithm, authentication, md5, sip

I am trying to Sip Register and I get the challenge from the server.

So I need to use the MD5 algorithm on the nonce and then send that to the server to authenticate.

I have come across two examples of MD5 encryption and I have tried both and each one gives a different string back to me, so I was wondering which one is the correct one to use?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Ok thanks for the commons codecs.

I have edited it because I have to encode the nonce value I get back from the server with my username and password to send it back.

So it is a particuler type of encoding for SIP registration, can anyone point to a tutorial on how to do this? Or have any hints?

Comment: FYI: MD5 is a *hash*, not a *cipher*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are incorrect. Your conversion from the byte array to a hexadecimal string is broken. I highly recommend using http://commons.apache.org/codec/ from the ASF which can do this for you:

```
Hex.encodeHexString(yourByteArray);
```

But if you're using commons-codec, you can also do this:

```
String sessionid = "1ddfdf99abfe5690dc1243875";
String md5HexString = DigestUtils.md5Hex(sessionid);
```

and you're done. Neat, isn't it? :-)

Comment: Whats the best way to do it without using the commons codec though? Not sure on the licencing of the commons codec

Comment: Apache Commons are liceneced under the Apache Licence which should not cause any harm. http://commons.apache.org/license.html or, if you prefer the Wikipedia entry without legalse: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License

Answer (score 1):

One obvious problem with the first one is that you produce the hex string the wrong way. When any value in `messageDigest` is less than 16, then you'll produce a single-digit hex string (for example `A`) instead of a two-digit one (`0A`).